# javascript loading conditional statement

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I've been struggling for days with getting rid of an error in IE, and to 'almost' no avail.

I just tried loading jquery 1.2.6 instead of 1.3.2, and the error has gone away (though the site is noticeably slower now).

However, I suspect I may be stuck with this solution. Is there a browser based way to include the script similar to the css conditional statements?

I can do it serverside if I need to, but client-side would be nice.

Comment: How about costing the code that gives the error to see if that can be fixed? Sounds like instead of fixing the problem, you just want to make it go away via a more complicated solution

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Conditional Comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512.aspx) to include script only for IE.

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        /*  Do Stuff */
    </script>
<![endif]-->
```

To exclude a script block from IE:

```
<![if !IE]>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        /*  Do Stuff */
    </script>
<![endif]>
```

Comment: but doing this means it will also load the other script if I can't specify NOT to load in IE.

Comment: I can't tell from your question that you're looking to run script on every browser *except* IE.  The document I linked in the answer has an example of how to do this: <![if !IE]><p>You are not using Internet Explorer.</p><![endif]>